# Restoring google cloudsql backup error, instance not in appropriate state

Tags: mysql, database-backups, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to restore a previous backup trough gconsole and json api as well and I am getting the error "The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request" what it means? I can't find in the docs, instance is on runnable status

I want to restore a backup because there was some data loss probably due to the fact I am using myisam instead of innodb, not sure if that matters with this issue

any idea?

Thank you

ps:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalidState",
"message": "The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request."
}
],
"code": 409,
"message": "The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request."
}
}
```

Comment: This usually happens when you try to restore from a backup that is too old. Cloud SQL only allows you to restore from the last 7 backups, this is mentioned on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Juan Enrique pointed out Cloud SQL [stores the seven last backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery#viewbackups), and it will allow you to restore any of them.

When using the API you may list backups that all the backups, including those older than the seven-last limit, but it won't allow you to restore from any of those.